# Why are opinion-based questions not worthy?

Tags: discussion

It seems here I can only ask others about some facts and not their opinions? It made me a bit confused, they say opinion based questions can't get any answer?!

I am doubtful if really opinion-based questions  are in anyway worthy and notable questions?

Does this strategy want to imply that opinion-based questions are not worthy and informative question at all?

Can I conclude that I never should ask such questions in any circumstances?! I mean even in my life outside this site?

**Update:**
If something is a question then I expect it has an answer, a question might be hard to answer or be vague. But I don't get what is an opinion-based question. Do you want to say it's in fact not a question?

Comment: Your question also contained at least 6 questions in it.  You've narrowed that down to 4 questions, and at least those 4 are similar enough that you have a bit of focus on it.

Comment: "Can I conclude that I never should ask such questions in any circumstances?! I mean even in my life outside this site?" Outside this site you ar free to ask whatever you want. Every site has its rules and this one is not an exception.

Comment: @convert LOL, the question is old and it's somehow philosophical. It's about "what is a question". I was afraid opinion-based questions are not actually questions!!! maybe I made it too complicated.

Answer (score 8):

The primary purpose of a Stack Exchange site for people to get answers to questions, and the primary way that they do that, is they find an existing question through a search engine like Google, and read the answer to that question.

When you're searching for something, and you come to a Q&A site like this, and you read a bunch of incomplete, subjective, or wrong answers, that's normally not very satisfying.  If you didn't find the information you're looking for, you would have just wasted your time coming here and reading through the answers.

To accomplish this end, we try to make our answers as complete and correct as possible.  When you ask a question where it's unreasonably difficult to write a complete and correct answer, then what tends to come are incomplete, subjective and wrong answers.  Subjective questions attract low-quality content.

---

When I come to a Stack Exchange post from Google, I expect to come away from that question with a piece of new information that I can rely on and make use of.  Opinions simply aren't reliable enough.

Comment: Objective questions receive facts and information and subjective or opinion based questions receive opinions, those who search for objective questions won't come across to a subjective question. And those search for subjective questions find opinions

Comment: It seems this site says subjective questions in fact are not questions, as you say they don't receive an informative answers? its my confusion. Why you say its opinion-based you could say its hard to answer.

Comment: @Ahmad The very definition of "opinion" it "neither unambiguously correct nor unambiguously incorrect"

Comment: Thank you! Actually as my update shows, I didn't get the meaning of opinion-based question. this guide was helpful.

Comment: Yes, maybe our required answer is not the accepted one. But maybe that is the answer by someone with many downvote. Many concepts in human based knowledges are opinion based. You can't escape it. You can see the school of thought of many philosophers. But if you can't converge on they're answer that is not meaning you must forbid them to question and answer.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question in your edit let me give you an example and while it might not be a political question it should help illustrate the issue.

> Is red or blue a better color.

In this question there is no one correct answer as everyone will have a different opinion on it and you could get many possible answers such as.

> It is clear red is the best color.

Or

> It is clear blue is the best color and everyone who thinks otherwise is wrong.

Or

> Both red and blue are horrible it is clear green is the only correct choice.

Or

> They are all equal and none are better then the other

The problem is that to all four people answering the question from their perspective and they are neither right or wrong.

Comment: Thanks, but how do you distinguish whether a question is opinion based or not? Maybe we say they don't have an object to apply the solution to it and see the result, or the object is human (but individuals and not all humans in general). Or they aren't testable maybe! So they aren't scientific maybe!!

Comment: @Ahmad that can be tricky depending on the question.

Answer (score -8):

I think the opinion based questions must be allowed and are valuable. Specially in human related questions. This is not important which answer is the accepted one. The accepted answer is the one the questioner has searched for. But maybe some other answer being accepted by some other reader. My question [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/78406/what-happens-in-afghanistan-according-to-wildcat-2022-documentary-movie?noredirect=1#comment334092_78406) has been closed since it is need opinion based answer. Because the question can have many opinion based answer. But this kind of answers can help us to make ourself more open-minded and to understand many group of peoples thoughts. As I've commented to one of answers: If you could not converge through philosophy and phycologists school of thought, that is not means you must forbid them to ask and answer based on the opinion. Because that is the only way the can ask and answer.

I condemn this strategy. The opinion based question like my questions are helpful.

Fredrich Niche:

> Truths are illusions which we have forgotten are illusions
>
> They are metaphors that have become worn out and have been drained of
> sensuous force, coins which have lost their embossing and are now
> considered as metal and no longer as coins.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/?_ga=2.261860618.664723788.1676415219-2082491870.1664015869 -- It seems to me the *primary* purpose of stackexchange sites is to share factual answers to commonly experienced practical problems, not to make people more open-minded nor to help people understand or debate other people's feelings. Of the SE sites I regularly read, politics.se is the least interesting and useful to me because it is the one that adheres least to these principles. Your goals are worthy but best served elsewhere.